# How to check Next-Js component state?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

So I'm adding react-placeholder package to my component but that requires `ready` parameter to take `this.state.ready`, what's the equivalent of that for nextjs?

When I try to `console.log(this)` in my component I just get 'undefined'.

Answer (score 0):

Ready is just plainly a true/false boolean value that you pass to the component.

Example

```
const [ ready, setReady ] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
   getData(); //fetch data on first load
},[])

const getData = async () => {
   const data = await fetch(api endpoint);
   if (data) return setReady(true) //data is ready
}
```

You can then use the following, where the placeholder will hide once the data is ready from API.

```
<ReactPlaceholder ready={ready}>
```

Comment: I have all the data, the issue is that rendering 50 components takes a noticeable delay, but if I render 50 placeholders it's instant.
So my plan is to just switch them when it's ready for render, can this be done?

Comment: you don't render 50 placeholders, you just render 1 place holder while the page is loading. What you need is probably react-lazyload, where you only load your component when it comes into view.

Comment: yes, lazyload is what I needed. thank you! :)